# How can I set the sample space for two random variables with 2 different discrete values for each?

Tags: probability

Say I have a group of athletes and I want to set two different random variables, $ X $ and $ Y $ to build a joint probability distribution of the two random variables. $ X $ has two different discrete values, for example, $ 0 = female $ and $ 1 = male $ and $ Y $ also has two different discrete values, for example, $ 0 = no medal $ and $ 1 = medal $. In this case, what could be the sample space and how can I visualize the sample space?

Comment: What about $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+%22sample+space%22+is%3Aquestion+score%3A1 for similar questions about sample spaces.